# Camel-openapi-java unable to calculate server url

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, openapi, camel-rest

I am migrating from camel-swagger-java-starter into camel-openapi-java-starter 3.20.5.

Camel-swagger was able to calculate the url server(scheme, host and port, while camel-openapi wasn't and displayed only the base path.

What was missing or incorrect ?

Another point that I should mention is that the application is deployed on jboss eap 7.

- Config:

  ```
   restConfiguration()
               .component("servlet")
               .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
               .apiProperty("base.path", "only-path")
               .apiContextPath("docs")
               .apiProperty("api.title", "title")
               .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
               .apiProperty("cors", apiEnableCors.toString())
               .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
               .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
               .apiVendorExtension(true);

   }
  ```